# Unable to set breakpoints inside node_modules (WebStorm)

Tags: webstorm, javascript-debugger

I use Webstorm to debug my applications. Setting breakpoints works great and my breakpoints will be hit by the debugger. If I set a breakpoint inside a script that is inside node_modules, then it doesn't work anymore. It should have something to do with WebStorm, because Node Inspector works fine with the same code.

It seems to be generic for all packages, but I have created a sample application that only uses the BlueBird package. Debug the following program inside WebStorm (make sure you run `npm install bluebird` before).

```
Promise = require('bluebird');

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Waiting 5 seconds...");
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Resolving...");
    resolve();
  }, 5000);
});

promise.then(function(){
  console.log("Resolved.");
});
```

This bogus program works fine. When I step into the `promise.then` part of the code I hit line 111 of promise.js (function `Promise.prototype.then` of the BlueBird package). When I set a breakpoint on that line and rerun the code, then it doesn't stop there. Breakpoints in my own code do work fine.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail as to what node module you are trying to debug? Or if you are using a specific node framework or anything like that?

Comment: I have changed my initial question, so it includes a very basic sample program (that doesn't work here).

Comment: Okay, I will see if I can reproduce the issue

Comment: I updated my post with a gif showing what I did. Let me know if I did what you are trying to do. I could be missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks similar to [WEB-18160](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18160), it's fixed in 11.0.2 that is coming soon

Comment: I've upgraded right now to version 11.0.2 of WebStorm only to discover that NONE of my breakpoints works anymore. It doesn't matter it they were set before and are set after upgrading it (from version 11.0.0).